# How get last segment of url using PCRE?

Tags: php, pcre

I have a url, - "`http://example.com/sales/view/id/705`" and I need get a last segment (705).

How can I do this using PCRE?

Comment: using PCRE is a primary words in my question.

Comment: `$pattern = '~http://example.com/sales/view/id/([0-9]+)~';` Can you expand a little bit more about why you need a pcre solution? I'm not questioning the need for it.. but your answer could significantly change the solution.

Comment: I need to add utm link (Analytics) for special link for this I'm using a preg_match with few rules.

Comment: Everyone who posted so far is assuming it's safe to ignore `http://example.com/sales/view/id/705?foo`, `http://example.com/sales/view/id/705?foo/bar`, `http://example.com/sales/view/id/705#foo` and `http://example.com/sales/view/id/705#foo/bar`. (Only the solution using URI works for these.) Is that truly the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(In PHP) I would not use PCRE for such a trivial and un-ambiguous job. I would just do:

```
$parts = explode('/', rtrim($url, '/'));
$partYouWant = array_pop($parts);
```

**EDIT**

If you need to use PCRE (although I don't know why you would) this variation on eugene y's answer would do it:

```
$pattern = '#/([^/]+)\z#';
$url = 'http://example.com/sales/view/id/705';
preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 6):

This should do it in Perl:

```
my ($last) = $url =~ /([^\/]+)\z/;
```

But I would rather use the [`URI`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI) module:

```
my $last = (URI->new($url)->path_segments)[-1];
```

Comment: Your regex can fail if the URL has a query or fragment, which goes to show why using [URI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI) is the smart way to go. +1 for mentioning the module.

Answer (score 4):

In PHP you can do this in a single line code:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/sales/view/id/705';
substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);
```

Comment: +1 - I suspect this would be less costly that my solution and would work in the same way. This may also require the `rtrim($url, '/');` although I only put this in a safe-guard against the URL potentially having a trailing slash, which may not be the case.

Comment: @DaveRandom I think this is faster too. As you point out it may not work in the case of a '/' at the end of string but it does not seems the case. Anyway seems that someone doesn't like my solution due to the -1 :)

Comment: I got one as well - but what can you do. At least it's costing the downvoter rep to downvote and not explain. I think you should lose -5 if you cast the first downvote and don't comment on the post.

Answer (score 2):

Non PCRE alternative:

```
$url="http://example.com/sales/view/id/705";
$lastPart = current(array_reverse((explode('/',parse_url($url,PHP_URL_PATH)))));
```

Doubt if it's any faster though

Answer (score 2):

You could use this pattern `([^\/]*)$` for everything from last `/` to end.

Maybe also interesting: `([^\/\?]*)(\?.*)?$` gives you everything between last `/` and first `?`

Answer (score 1):

Say no to PCRE if you can,:-).

```
echo basename('http://example.com/sales/view/id/705');
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest:

```
  $ok=preg_match('#\d+$#',$url,$m);
  if($ok)
    echo $m[0],"\n";
```

Brainy:

```
  $ok=preg_match('#/(\d+)$#',$url,$m);
  if($ok)
    echo $m[1],"\n";
```

Flexible: (as it also allows words, other than digits)

```
  $ok=preg_match('#/(\w+)$#',$url,$m);
  if($ok)
    echo $m[1],"\n";
```

More flexible: (as it now allows everything that's not a / to match)

```
  $ok=preg_match('#/(.*?)$#',$url,$m);
  if($ok)
    echo $m[1],"\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('@/([1-9]\d*)/?(?:$|\?)@', $url, $matches);//$matches[1] contains your id
```